# Include sitemap in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, sitemap

I generated a normal sitemap with an online Sitemalgenerator:
http://xml-sitemaps.com

Now I tried to include it like every other Sitemap on a Server.
The problem is, on this Server seems to be a CakePHP Framework and I dont know, how it works cause
I dont have any experience in PHP.

The error:

> Missing Controller
>   Error: `Sitemap.xmlController` could not be found.
>   Error: Create the class `Sitemap.xmlController` below in file: `app/Controller/Sitemap.xmlController.php`
>
> ```
> <?php
> class Sitemap.xmlController extends AppController {
> }
> ```

Can you tell me, how to include a XML Sitemap in the easiest way? I'm a beginner in Webprogramming!
(I dont want to create a dynamic Sitemap)

Thank you!

Comment: The file needs to be placed in webroot folder.

Answer (score 0):

Place your file in your webroot folder:

```
app/webroot/Sitemap.xml
```

As long as the file is found in the webroot CakePHP will load it, if the file is not found it will run through its normal application request cycle based on your defined routes.